# is there a more efficient way to calculate a joint pmf table in Python or R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compute a joint pmf.

```
 x    P(X=x)        y    P(Y=y)
 0     1/16         0     1/2
 1     4/16         1     1/4
 2     6/16         2     1/8
 3     4/16         3     1/16
 4     1/16         4     1/16
```

to get a probability of an event such as P(X=3, Y=2) = 1/16, more info at this [post](http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/~radford/sta247.F11/lec4.html).

I have to construct a joint pmf table

```
      y=   0      1      2      3      4
      -------------------------------------
 x=   |                                    |
    0 |   1/16    0      0      0      0   |
      |                                    |
    1 |   3/16   1/16    0      0      0   |
      |                                    |
    2 |   3/16   2/16   1/16    0      0   |
      |                                    |
    3 |   1/16   1/16   1/16   1/16    0   |
      |                                    |
    4 |    0      0      0      0     1/16 |
      |                                    |
```

[this post](https://pythonhosted.org/prob140/joint_tutorial.html) provide a way to do this, condition on a list of existing probabilities.

for now, I have to compute the list manually.

is there a more efficient way to calculate these individual probabilities automatically in Python or R?

Comment: How do you get `P(X=3, Y=2) = 1/16` ? You cannot get the joint probabilities from only the marginal ones.

Comment: If you assume that the joint distribution is separable (i.e. X and Y are independent), you can compute P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)P(y=y) (i.e. compute all the pairwise products).  Otherwise, *the* joint distribution is not uniquely defined by the marginal distributions, and you need more information.